# Picking out elements of an array according to a specific rule

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, extract

So I have a *100000*-by-*2* matrix in MATLAB. I want to extract only the elements in the second column which all have the same element for their corresponding row in the first column. E.g. if we have:

```
A = [1  2
     3  4
     2  6
     1  5
     4  1
     1  3]
```

and then specify that we want all elements in the second column with `1` as their corresponding value in the 1st column. So I would want the above to become:

```
2
5
3
```

Does anyone know how to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: `A( find(A(:,1)==1) , 2  )` will do what you want. Read the Matlab documentation on logical indexing.

Comment: You can even drop the `find`, so it becomes `A( A(:,1)==1, 2)`

Comment: oops ... silly me referring to logical indexing and yet still using `find`. @hbaderts is right, forget the `find`, but still read about logical indexing in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks! Worked exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: @Hoki post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab supports matrix operations, so you can do what you want without having to explicitly loop through the entire matrix like some other languages.

By using logical indexing, (more on that here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true)
you can extract the necessary elements from your matrix.

First you want to create a [0,1] array of rows in your matrix that satisfy your condition.

You can do that with 
A(:,1) == 1

This will produce

1
0
0
1
0
1

Which means that the first, fourth and last rows satisfy the condition where the element in the first column of the matrix satisfies the condition that it equals one.

Now you can use this to produce the elements in the second column, by simply using it as an index of your original matrix.

A(A(:,1)==1,2)

to produce the required result.